# PySpark groupBy with grouped elements

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have about 2 billion records and I want to group data with PySpark and save each grouped data to csv.

Here is my sample Dataframe:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | date                |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | a    | 2019-12-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | b    | 2019-12-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | c    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | a    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | b    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | a    | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | b    | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

Then I use groupBy to group them with this code:

```
df.groupBy([
  'name',
  year('date').alias('year'),
  month('date').alias('month')
]).count()
```

output:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| name | year | month | count |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| a    | 2019 | 12    | 1     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| b    | 2019 | 12    | 1     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| c    | 2020 | 01    | 1     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| a    | 2020 | 01    | 2     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| b    | 2020 | 01    | 2     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

But I want each group elements in Dataframe like this:

```
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| name | year | month | element   |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| a    | 2019 | 12    | Dataframe |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| b    | 2019 | 12    | Dataframe |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| c    | 2020 | 01    | Dataframe |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| a    | 2020 | 01    | Dataframe |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| b    | 2020 | 01    | Dataframe |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
```

Where "element column" contains grouped Dataframe in each group then I want to map each group and save them to separate csv.

> Note: I have tried to use distinct and collect for grouping then select data for each group, but performance is too slow for my huge data. I think groupBy is faster, so I want to use groupBy instead.

How to do it in PySpark ?

Comment: for element column value should be Dataframe only right, in other word you have to add element column with Dataframe value right?

Comment: @JayKakadiya Yes, and it should be group members

Answer (score 0):

you can achive your goal using `withcolumn` and `lit`

```
df.groupBy(['name',year('date').alias('year'),month('date').alias('month')])
.withColumn('element',lit('Dataframe'))
```